# Reporting and knife runs command for opensource chef

Tags: chef-infra, knife

Chef reporting doc says its for Enterprise chef. 
For opensource chef I am able to get JSON reports which is getting stored in same directory for all nodes. Is there any better way of reporting fof opensource chef?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using a [ReportHandler](https://docs.chef.io/handlers.html) to report statistics into our Zabbix monitoring at the end of chef-client runs: [here](https://github.com/TYPO3-cookbooks/zabbix-custom-checks/blob/master/templates/chef-client/chef-client-handler.rb). You can adopt this example to your needs.

Comment: If you have something different in mind, please elaborate a bit more in detail. Your question is rather broad.

Comment: [chef doc](http://docs.opscode.com/handlers.html#reporting) says that it stores reports in chef server. how we can use it with opensource chef.I added it in report handler , That version check makes it to go else block. I ma looking for a way to store reports in chef server itself

Comment: What values do you want to have reported?