# Reporting plugin for Opensource chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

Is there any Plugin to add reporting feature to an opensource chef as it is for Enterprise chef?

I tried installing using below command

> ```
>       /opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem install knife-reporting
> ```

knife-reporting gem got install but no related commands are found when i run knife

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reporting and knife runs command for opensource chef](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630230/reporting-and-knife-runs-command-for-opensource-chef)

Answer (score 1):

Knife-Reporting plugin is used to analyze the reports sent by clients to the server.
[knife runs help ] run this command to find the new functionalists given by knife reporting. 
[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630230/reporting-and-knife-runs-command-for-opensource-chef) Seems to be a similar question.
[chef doc](http://docs.opscode.com/handlers.html#reporting) has the code for handling the report and sending it to the server. It has to be shipped with chef handler cookbook and enabled before chef run.

For getting json files which contains all info about node run as report.
Get chef_handler from community.
Add recipe[chef_handler::json_file] in your run list. This will get the report as a json file and store in your /var/chef/reports (can be changed in chef_handler cookbook) in client machine.

Comment: How did you install that plugin on opensource chef.Because i cant find any command with knife runs

Comment: it has to be shipped with chef handler cookbook.I am able to get json reports using chef handler cookbooks json handler recipe. I am working on the plugin. Once its done i will let you know. This is the way to do.If some body knows , Please help.

Comment: I added json report handler usage in answer which stores the report in chef client machine. Need to find a way to export it to server

Comment: I tried as you suggested.Everything worked fine iam able to find logs at node.Please post when you find a way to export it to server.